# How do I change my label in customcell using the "void" didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this problem. Use UICollectionView with my class "myCustomCell" where I inserted a label that I have to change. When I use the method:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [self colorForIndexToBlack:indexPath.item];
        UIColor *colorCell = cell.backgroundColor;
        NSString *strColorCell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", colorCell.hexStringValue];
        cell.lblCustomCell.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HEX %@", strColorCell];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [self colorForIndexToWhite:indexPath.item];
        UIColor *colorCell = cell.backgroundColor;
        NSString *strColorCell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", colorCell.hexStringValue];
        cell.lblCustomCell.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HEX %@", strColorCell];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

**lblCustomCell** (which is my label to be changed) is filled with the information i want and it's ok. But when i use this method **"void"** to select a single cell and edit the text of the label does not work and does not change the label with my new text.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [self colorForIndexToBlack:indexPath.item];
        UIColor *colorCell = cell.backgroundColor;
        NSString *strColorCell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", colorCell.hexStringValue];
        cell.lblCustomCell.text = strColorCell;
        NSLog(@"Indice della cella: %i %i %@", indexPath.item, indexPath.section * 2 + indexPath.row, strColorCell);
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [self colorForIndexToWhite:indexPath.item];
        UIColor *colorCell = cell.backgroundColor;
        NSString *strColorCell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", colorCell.hexStringValue];
        cell.lblCustomCell.text = strColorCell;
        NSLog(@"Indice della cella: %i %i %@", indexPath.item, indexPath.section * 2 + indexPath.row, strColorCell);
    }
}
```

How can fix?

Comment: what do you mean with when you use void?

Comment: With this method you should use didSelectItemAtIndexPath "void", like this:
- (Void) CollectionView: (UICollectionView *) CollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now, you are not getting the cell correctly in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method.
To get the cell, use this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

And change whatever you want, for example:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      if (indexPath.section == 0) {
         cell.backgroundColor = [self colorForIndexToBlack:indexPath.item];
         UIColor *colorCell = cell.backgroundColor;
         NSString *strColorCell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",     colorCell.hexStringValue];
        cell.lblCustomCell.text = strColorCell;
         NSLog(@"Indice della cella: %i %i %@", indexPath.item, indexPath.section * 2 + indexPath.row, strColorCell);
     } else {
         cell.backgroundColor = [self colorForIndexToWhite:indexPath.item];
         UIColor *colorCell = cell.backgroundColor;
         NSString *strColorCell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", colorCell.hexStringValue];
         cell.lblCustomCell.text = strColorCell;
         NSLog(@"Indice della cella: %i %i %@", indexPath.item, indexPath.section * 2 + indexPath.row, strColorCell);
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm missing something ... I do not understand what to change and where and I do not work...

Comment: I'm trying, but says: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'CustomCell *' with an expression of type 'UICollectionViewCell *'

Comment: I forgot to add the cast of the first line, see my edit here:CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: Ok, clear and done. But you can only accept one answer right?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get your cell object with the previous method.-

```
CustomCell *cell = [self collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```